# Please guide me how to code tooltip in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, tooltip

I never used WPF , tooltip before I am assigned to implement textbox that receieve number in range 1-999 if it out of this range tooltip will be shown near the textbox and textbox is changedto red border while input is out of range. pls guide me i try to bind xaml and function in C# but nothing happen

```
<TextBox  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="276" Margin="73,71,0,0" PreviewTextInput="PreviewTextInput" PreviewKeyDown="TextboxPreviewKeydown" >
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Number">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <ExceptionValidationRule />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

and my C#

```
public int Number
    {
        get { return num; }
        set 
        {
            num = value;
            if (value <= 0 || value >999)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Out of range");
            }
        }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.tooltip.aspx

Have you even tried googling for wpf tooltip ?

Comment: yep i try to code many time but the result is not match what i want

Comment: Then why have you not posted your code , and asked what you are doing wrong ?

Comment: i am sorry ,i already added my Code

Answer (score 0):

In simplest way you can do this:

```
        <TextBox Text="{Binding}">
            <TextBox.ToolTip>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/> // Here you can bind to property or give static value to show in tooltip
            </TextBox.ToolTip>
        </TextBox>
```

Thanks

Comment: @Gozilla, we don't need the thank you comments.  Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and accept nit's answer or explain why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to build a validation rule

You create a class ("MyValidation" for example) that extends "ValidationRule" and you implement it
Then in your xaml, you can do this

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Text>
     <Binding...>
       <Binding.ValidationRules>
          <local:MyValidation/>
       </Binding.ValidationRules>
     </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```